# Ionic v3 + Capacitor : ERROR TypeError: Object(...)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I just moved an ionic v3 app from Cordova to Capacitor. The iOS build worked right away. However, it's been nearly a week since I am having troubles running the app on Android.

I currently do not have any cordova plugin or npm package about Firebase. When I run the app from Android Studio, I get the following error:
[image]

I looked at many posts like this one : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function/130589/13 but nothing solved my issue.

However, I have seen some posts online saying that this kind of error could be related to an error in the app modules provider.

That got me thinking: Do I need to add anything to the providers in order to get capacitor android working? The app run perfectly on Cordova and Capacitor iOS.

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a custom plugin that was using an older version of firebase (causing a google services version conflict).

I also downloaded an ionic v4 plugin! This causes the famous Object() is not a function error!

Hope this post can help!